# Функция с переменным числом параметров не выделяет память

Tags: c++, функции

Когда я писал функцию, которая выделяет память под n параметров, используя макросы va_*, она неправильно выделяла память под структуру.

Сама функция:

```
typedef   signed __int64 Tint;
typedef unsigned __int64 Tuint;

typedef Tint *Pint;

struct Numx
{
    Tint
        alen, // Allocated data length (in Tint units)
        len,  // Used data length (in Tint units), 0 = zero, -1 = variable, -2 = fraction, -5 = range, -12 = matrix
        sgn,  // Sign, plus == 0, minus == 1
        exp,  // Exponent (how many Tints has integer part)
        m,    // Mantissa (most significant digits are at the beginning)
        d,    // Divisor (a number by which another number is to be divided)
        reserved[12];
};

Pint ALLOCX(Tint len)
{   // Функция выделяет память под структуру и возвращает указатель на мантиссу
    if (len == 0)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    Numx *numx = new Numx[sizeof(Numx) + sizeof(Tint) * (len - 1)];

    numx->alen = len;
    numx->len = 0;
    numx->sgn = 0;
    numx->exp = 1;
    numx->d = 1;

    return &(numx->m);
}

// Аргументы после "len" имеют тип Pint
Pint __cdecl ALLOCN(int n, Tint len, ...)
{
    if (n == 0 || len == 0)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    va_list arg_ptr;
    va_start(arg_ptr, len);

    while (n--)
        va_arg(arg_ptr, Pint) = ALLOCX(len);

    va_end(arg_ptr);
}
```

Но если вывести адреса, которые присваиваются переменным:

```
ALLOCN(2, 1, &x, &y);
std::cout << x << '\n' << y;
```

Выводится:

```
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

Хотя должно выводится что-то вроде:

```
00000000004C36E0
00000000004C8CA0
```

Вопрос: в чем проблема? Почему выводится некорректный адрес памяти?

Comment: Очевидно выражение `va_arg(arg_ptr, Pint) = ALLOCX(len);` изменяет параметры функции, то бишь локальные переменные. Чтобы измениться значения переменных в вызывающей функции вам надо было передавать указатели на эти переменные и потом их разыменовывать. А вообще все это не нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну так что это за белиберда

```
va_arg(arg_ptr, Pint) = ALLOCX(len);
```

Почему вы пытаетесь писать что-то прямо в результат `va_arg(arg_ptr, Pint)`? Результат `va_arg` даже не обязан являться lvalue.

Вам нужно

```
*va_arg(arg_ptr, Pint *) = ALLOCX(len);
```

а лучше вообще не лепить все в одну строку

```
Pint *p = va_arg(arg_ptr, Pint *);
*p = ALLOCX(len);
```

P.S. Отдельно не ясно, что именно вы собираетесь возвращать из своей `ALLOCX`.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
*(va_arg(arg_ptr, Pint*)) = ALLOCX(len);
```

Надеюсь, `x` и `y` - это `Pint`?

Семантику, так сказать, не смотрел, так что все остальные ошибки не проверял.

Comment: С "хацкерской" токи зрения владение указателем на `Numx->m` позволяет восстановить `Numx`, т.е. потери нет.

Comment: @AnT Ну... а вообще-то, да, вы правы. Убираю :)